# How can I prevent my connection to automatically disconnect when I lock my screen?

Tags: networking, network-manager

How can I prevent my (WiFi) connection to automatically disconnect when I lock my screen? Note that this problem does not occur on my home LAN for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you enable the connection "for all users" (you can set a checkbox for this when you edit the connection properties) it should not drop anymore.

Comment: This solution was from a while ago, but in case anyone stumbles on this thread, I'm on 20.04 and have this checkbox checked, but the WiFi still dropped when the screen locked.

Answer (score 0):

The only method that I found that worked is to disable suspend and hibernate altogether. This may not be a suitable solution for some laptop users, but I don't use those features so this solution worked out well. That said, it would be nice if there was a more elegant solution to this.

To do this, use Dconf Editor to go to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` and set active to *false*.

The next time you lock your session, your WiFi should stay connected.

Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/1091367/ubuntu-16-04-cannot-prevent-wifi-sleep-during-screen-lock

PS: It's amusing that this question was asked in 2011, and here we are. Such is the nature of open-source I suppose.