# is there some way to turn off WIFI when the screen is locked?

Tags: networking, wireless, lock-screen

I would like that, everytime I lock the screen (or it auto locks), that WIFI gets disconnected/sleep/disabled.
And everytime I unlock it, the WIFI auto connects again.
Best would be if it checked for internet activity and kept WIFI ON, even if the screen gets locked, until some download ends, and turn it OFF just after that.

I keep my notebook connected on power, so the answer shall not depend on battery saving I think?

**Changing some settings that did not help:**

unchecking "make available to other users" did not work: (inverse of) https://askubuntu.com/a/21372/589343

"wifi can be turned off to save power" doesnt seem to work, I guess it is because I keep it connected on power?

Comment: I am trying this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28183/235896

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28183/235896, I was using this:

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
  while read str; do
    echo "$str"
    case "$str" in 
      *"boolean true"*)  echo SCREEN_LOCKED  ;nmcli networking off;;
      *"boolean false"*) echo SCREEN_UNLOCKED;nmcli networking on ;;
    esac
  done
```

But once, the screen wokeup all in black and showed only the mouse and the internet was activated, I have no idea what happened...

---

So this one https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449013/235896, seems to be more reliable:

```
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 |
  while read str; do
    echo "$str"
    case "$str" in 
      *"LockedHint': <true>"*)  echo SCREEN_LOCKED  ;date;nmcli networking off;;
      *"LockedHint': <false>"*) echo SCREEN_UNLOCKED;date;nmcli networking on ;;
    esac
  done
```

Obs.: I will try to add internet activity check later...